# How do I get the html file of the public folder from Nextjs?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to show you the file of the working HTML as a nextjs component Please help me

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Content = dynamic(() =>
  fetch("/js-tetris/index.html").then((res) => res.json())
);
const GameComponent = () => {
  const [html, sethtml] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/js-tetris/index.html")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((text) => sethtml(text));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="h-screen">
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
};
export default GameComponent;
```

## error message

> TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /js-tetris/index.html